# How to prevent '\n' being passed as input?

Tags: c, pointers, io, user-input, getchar

When we execute the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char x,y;
    scanf("%c", &y);
    x = getchar();
    putchar(x);
    return 0;
}
```

The enter that is being inputted in the `scanf("%c", &y);` statement is passed on to x. Is there some way to get away with this? I now that if we are using `scanf` then we can ignore the `\n` by `scanf("%*c%c", &x);` but don't know what do while using `getchar()`.

Comment: Clear the input buffer

Comment: please clarify what do you mean by that

Comment: It the goal is to read a _line_ of user input, start with `fgets()` and a generous sized buffer,  Then parse the buffer for `char y`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the best way, but it will work in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c. Do it before calling `getchar`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP wants to do the same thing using `getchar`.

Comment: First of all you need to remember (or learn) that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`**. This is important for any `EOF` check that you really need to have. The second thing to solve your problem is to read character by character in a loop until you have read the newline (or hit end-of-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char x,y,ch;

    scanf("%c%*c", &y);
    while((ch=getchar())!='\n'&&ch!=EOF); //removes all character in input buffer
    x = getchar();
    putchar(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the problem of the input buffer, In your case, you can use alternative input-string getchar() with fflush(stdin); for handling this issue.

Comment: The second `scanf` doesn't need the `getchar` call, all you need is to tell `scanf` to skip leading white-space by adding a single space in the format string: `scanf(" %c", &b);`

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is UB.

Comment: @Amandeep The C specification explicitly say that passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is UB. One common compiler unfortunately adds it as a non-portable extension of the language. Such extensions should be avoided (at all cost IMO).